# AngularJS: Firing an Event to Invoke a Service Method inside a Controller Method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In code below I've created a module with a service and a controller. The service contains a single method which I am sharing and invoking within the controller. This code below represents a working implementation:

```
 !(function() {
      'use strict';

      var app = angular.module('app', []);

      app.service('rootService', function() {
        this.exampleFunction = function() {
          alert('this is running from the service');
        };
      });

      app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'rootService',
        function($scope, rootService) {
            rootService.exampleFunction();
        }]);
    })();
```

This is my question:

I'd like to invoke the method in the controller only when an event is fired. When I add a listener for the click event and fire off a function to invoke the same method, the error console returns: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function."

Here's the code I'm attempting:

```
!(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.service('rootService', function() {
    this.exampleFunction = function() {
      alert('this is running from the service');
    };
  });

  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'rootService',
    function($scope, rootService) {

      var button = document.getElementByTag(button);
      button.addEventListener('click', function(rootService) {
        rootService.exampleFunction();
      });
    }
  ]);
})();
```

Why doesn't this work? What largely changes between these 2 implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, specifically answering your question, issues about whether it is the correct way or not, when you attach a click handler to anything, when it fires, it receives an `Event` object, and not `rootService`.

`Event` has no method `exampleFunction` and so you get your undefined message.

One possible fix for you would be to define the click handler in your template.

```
<button ng-click="callExampleFunction()">Click</button>
```

And change your controller.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'rootService',
    function($scope, rootService) {
        $scope.callExampleFunction = function(){
            rootService.exampleFunction();
        });
    }
  ]);
```

Additionally, I wanted to point out for future readers, there is another bug in the question code.

```
var button = document.getElementByTag(button);
```

That statement will not work; document has a [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName) method, not `getElementByTag`. `getElementsByTagName` takes a string argument and returns an array, so the corrected code (to find the first button) would be

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
```

Finally, in Angular, click handlers are easily handled with `ng-click`. And if you really needed to attach a click handler without using `ng-click`, you would be better off doing it in a directive, using [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

```
angular.element("button").on("click", function(){...})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The event I'm actually listening for in my app is a window resize. Would I use a directive for that, like @Josh Beam recommends?

Comment: @shmuli Yes, in that case, a directive is probably more appropriate. Googling angular window resize directive will give you some quick examples.

Comment: Why does this differ from writing an event listener in a controller that invokes a **local** method? That works without problems... It's only when I attempt invoking a method from the **service** within the controller that I have the problem that I'm unable to do this with an event listener.

Comment: @shmuli Without seeing the code, I would imagine it's because the "local" method is in the same Javascript scope (not to be confused with Angular scope) as the event handler you were declaring. In other words, if you defined a function you wanted to call, and the event handler both inside the controller, then the event handler can see the other function because they are in the same scope. Your service's method, however, is in a different Javascript scope and your handler cannot see it without some reference.

Comment: Doesn't wrapping all these methods (the service, the controller and its contained methods) within an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) place it in the same scope?

Comment: No. Functions can only see what is inside their own declaration and their parent functions. If you have to functions declared at the same level (two different functions in the same IIFE) they cannot see variables declared inside one another. They could both, however, see things declared in their common parent.

Comment: Got it. So one method within the controller can see another method in that same controller. But it can't reach beyond its scope and see the service method. In this case, however, I injected the service into the controller as a dependency, and then I called the service method as an argument within the controller method. Why does such "injection" not give me access to what's declared outside the scope? Isn't dependency injection common Angular practice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71456/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-shmuli).

Answer (score 1):

The `addEventListener` callback is happening in the global context, not in the context of your controller.

This is why it is recommended you use directives for DOM manipulation, events, etc. The basis of AngularJS is separation of concerns, and you'll likely run into problems such as the one you're having if you structure your app in a way that conflicts with that principle of modularization.

**EDIT**

I suggested using an explicit user-defined directive, but an `ng-click` referencing a function in your controller would serve a similar purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different spaces when we are using `angular`, i.e., `angular-space` and `non-angular-space`. The browser events like `addEventListener` and all `jQuery` listeners belong in `non-angular-space` so the listeners will not work in `angular-space`. There are equivalent listeners directives for almost all browser event and we have to use those directives instead. In this case the directive is `ng-click`.

Hope it makes sense.